# Issue on Adding Wegits to Group in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know how I can add the `label` and `Combobox` to the `group`

as you can see I already declared the
    group = LabelFrame(app, text="Group")
    group.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

but not sure how to add wedgies tho that?

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()
app.configure(background='DimGray')
app.geometry('600x600')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

note = Notebook(app)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tracing", compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Network Details")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

group = LabelFrame(app, text="Group")
group.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

lb1 = Label(tab1,  text="Trace Object")
lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)


variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")

cm = ttk.Combobox(tab1, textvariable=variable)
cm.config(values =('Select From Phase A', 'Select From Phase B'))
cm.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)


app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument for any tkinter widget is the master widget. If you use 'group' as master, then that widget gets added to the group widget.

```
group = LabelFrame(app, text="Group")
group.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

lb1 = Label(group,  text="Trace Object")
lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

cm = ttk.Combobox(group, textvariable=variable)
cm.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but I am not sure why I am not seeing the border! the group title is showing on the app but no border!

Comment: No idea; I tested it and it shows the border for me.